# Custom sort and column header sorting on datagridview

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

what I have so far,

```
dim activeTable as DataTable
activeTable = testDataset.Tables("Test")

With DataGridView1
  .Datasource = activeTable
  .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
  .Sort(dgvLoadInformation.Columns(0), 
    System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
  .MultiSelect = False
End With
```

the sorted table

```
ID          Type       Name       Quantity
A-001       A          Name1      1
ABC-0001    ABC        Name       2
B-001       B          Name4      2
C-001       C          Name3      5
```

For 'Type' column, only four possible values (A, B, C, ABC)

Wanted sort result:

```
ID          Type       Name       Quantity
A-001       A          Name1      1
B-001       B          Name4      2
C-001       C          Name3      5
ABC-0001    ABC        Name       2
```

Also is it possible whenever the 'ID' and 'Type' column header is click it sorts the whole datagrid just like the wanted sort order.

Comment: I don't know for you but in my DGV when I click the column it automatically sorts by default by alphabetical order.

Comment: @Mederic, yes it sort alphabetically when the column header is clicked, but the sort order I want is not sorted by alphabetical order. What I want to happen is sort the table just like the "Wanted sort result" part of my question.

Comment: In that case i think you would need to create your own sort algorithm. you could have an array that has your types by order for eg: `{"ABC","C","B","A"}` Then you would just do a for (loop) each value in the array if the row = the value move row to top. then youll have everything sorted in reversed of your array so A --> B --> C --> ABC

Comment: If the DGV uses a datasource (and it should) then do not loop thru rows - use a custom sorter on the datasource.  I am sure those 4 elements dont provide a complete picture so its hard to provide more help.